# react native when navigate back the flat list resets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I'm scrolling in flat list to the center and then navigating to the next screen then navigate back to the pervious screen, the scroll will go back to the start on the flatlist.

I'm navigating using

```
this.props.navigation.goBack('SCREEN_A')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How does your navigation tree look like? How do you get the data for the flat list? There are different reasons for the list to be reset, and your question does not provide enough info.

Comment: @ThoVu flatlist gets its data from redux

Answer (score 0):

You can use NavigationAction.back() method. Look at [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#back)

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const backAction = NavigationActions.back({
  key: 'Profile',
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(backAction);
```

i think this works for you:

```
dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
```

Comment: Hello, when i add the key it doesn't do anything

Comment: Key should be navigate FROM not TO. in Example. if you want to go back to ScreenA from ScreenB use ScreenB for key